# stop jQuery effect on click?

Tags: jquery

why doesn't this stop my effect once the .pulse class is pushed?

```
jQuery(".pulse").effect("pulsate", { times:100 }, 2000).click(function(){
        jQuery(".pulse").effect().stop();
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `jQuery(".pulse").stop()` ?

Comment: I tried that originally... the answer below resolves the issue completly though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is in specifying the 2 very important arguments of `.stop()` which allows you to clear all queued animation steps and jump straight to the end state of the animation - See the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

```
jQuery(".pulse").effect("pulsate", { times:1000 }, 2000).click(function(){
    jQuery(this).stop(true, true);
});
```

See this **DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/YGTLq/

Comment: thank you  works a charm you are a star, I have been coding all through the night. I just didn't notice that.....